# org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64

Tags: apache-kafka, apple-m1, snappy

I'm building a cdc pipeline to read mysql binlog through maxwell and putting them into kafka my compression type is snappy in maxwell config.But at consumer end in my spring project I'm getting this error.

```
org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.findNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:361) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:195) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:167) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.init(Snappy.java:69) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:46) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:435) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:466) ~[snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:1.1.7.7]
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:271) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readUnsignedVarint(ByteUtils.java:170) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:205) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:296) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$2.doReadRecord(DefaultRecordBatch.java:278) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$StreamRecordIterator.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:617) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:582) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:551) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1578) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1613) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1700(Fetcher.java:1454) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:687) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:638) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1299) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1233) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1206) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.2.jar:na]
```

My java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
and using Apple M1 chip.

Comment: Have you tried installing snappy libraries with homebrew?

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer after adding dependency its working .

Comment: @jss How did you add dependency?

Comment: @jss what dependency did you add?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
            <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to update snappy version to `1.1.8.4` or later:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
      <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Source:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11863?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17318180#comment-17318180